# Getting 301 moved permanently response on Laravel API post request

Tags: angular, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have deployed Laravel REST API app on Digitalocean LAMP. I am using Angular 4 as frontend. When I make a post request to API I get a 301 Moved permanently response. It's working fine if I send the required through Advanced REST API client and worked properly on local dev setup as well.

CORS has been set up on Laravel.

Any suggestions will be very useful here. Have currently tried it on Chrome only

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
      Options -MultiViews
   </IfModule>

   php_flag opcache.enable Off

   RewriteEngine On

   # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder…
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=307]

   # Handle Front Controller…
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

   # Handle Authorization Header
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
   RewriteRule .* — [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

[Laravel return empty response / laravel 301 Moved Permanently](https://medium.com/@mshanak/laravel-return-empty-response-690f8a308d9a)